# R - XLSX: Add one value to an existing excel table

Tags: r, excel, xlsx

I have a very straight forward Problem, that is rather Standard I think. Unfortunately I have some difficulties to find the correct Syntax to solve it. I simply want to write data (here: one simple integer) to an existing excel table.

I figured out, that a good way to do that is using the package 'xlsx'.

```
require(xlsx)      # Load the xlsx package
```

Next I would have to load the file, and load all the sheets.

```
wb <- loadWorkbook("test.excelfile.xls")    # Load the xls file
sheets <- getSheets(wb)                     # load all sheet objects
```

Then I enter the values. These are the lines that generate errors.

```
addDataFrame(data.frame(123), sheets[1])    # Error in addDataFrame(data.frame(123), sheets[1]) :   attempt to apply non-function
addDataFrame(123, sheets[1])                # alternative try, same error
```

At the end I save the workbook.

```
saveWorkbook(wb, "test.excelfile.xls")   # not checked yet because error occurs in line above
```

It is important for me that the already existent xls file is not destroyed. I want to keep all the work sheets, VBA macros and form elements. Only some cells should be changed from within R.

Thank you very much for your help,

Matthias

Comment: Don't you need to add the dataframe to a cell?  You are just supplying a worksheet name, but you'll need the full range.

Comment: If it's a single value, why did you make it a `dataframe` ? Just take your single value and use any of the Excel connection tools to write to the designated spreadsheet cell of your choice.

Comment: @jbarker2160: You are right. It is only one cell. Therefor, the addDataFrame method allows to give a 'StartRow' and 'StartColumn'. On default they are both set to 1. If you don't want to write to the cell (1,1) you could simply change them.

Comment: @CarlWitthoft: Didn't I make it a dataframe? Once I tried the input argument 123 and I also tried data.frame(123). But both resulted in the same error: 'attempt to apply non-function'.
'any of the Excel connection tools' sounds useful. What do you mean by that? Can you give me a link, please? Thank you!

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Finally I managed to do what I was looking for. I googled a bit more for 'Excel connection tools' (see Carl Witthoft's commend) and found that a good package to use is XLConnect.

The following commands write a simple number to one cell. They also leave the VBA macro intact.

```
require(XLConnect)

# Load workbook; create if not existing
wb <- loadWorkbook("MC_Auswertung.xls", create = TRUE)

# write to the workbook
writeWorksheet(wb, 750, sheet="Auswertung",   # write '750' to sheet 'Auswertung' in workbook 'wb' 
           startRow=8, startCol=4,            # specify the cell to write to
           header=FALSE)                      # do not write a header row

# Save workbook
saveWorkbook(wb)
```

There is just one thing that strikes me. Before the operation the xls-file had 32.953 byte. After the operations above it only had 28.958 byte. So a significant amount of 'data' disappeared. I have no idea what has gone? The cell contents are still there. So are the diagrams, background and border styles, ...

Looking forward to you commands ;-)

Comment: Does this work with excel table? E.g. if the number of rows change will all of it be loaded into a connected pivot table?